# Python 3.x website and app GUI

Tags: user-interface, web, python-3.x, cjk

I am only starting out to learn programming, currently on Python 3.2, and was looking to build a few simple applications and possibly website(s), also simple. I want to know a good GUI library to start that:

1. is simple with good control (not a major issue, I'm planning to advance as much as possible anyway);
2. is cross-platform, with a native feel;
3. has good tutorials somewhere (please post link);
4. I can use to sell applications/make profit from websites with little to no licensing issues (a must);
5. can use Chinese characters as strings (not a must, but would definitely be a game changer).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main options for cross platform GUIs in Python 3:

- Tkinter is simple and ships with Python, but applications can look a bit ugly. I like [this site](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/) for learning it, although it's a bit old.
- Qt is bigger and more complex, but produces powerful, good looking applications. If you want to make proprietary software with it, you'll need to use `PySide`, rather than `PyQt`, but how you use them is almost identical. There are plenty of tutorials online (mainly for PyQt, which has been around longer, but they're fine if you're using PySide).

Both should handle any characters, including Mandarin, so long as the system has fonts with those characters to display them.

Most of the tutorials for both will be based on Python 2, so you'll have to make a few changes. `print "foo"` becomes `print("foo")`, and `Tkinter` becomes `tkinter`, for example.

Comment: @LennartRegebro: I've never really worked out how to integrate Python & QML. Do you know of a good tutorial?

Comment: I would have assumed there is one in the PySide docs, if not, then I don't. I was shown it.

Comment: @LennartRegebro: Good call - I found http://qt-project.org/wiki/Hello_World_in_PySide_and_QtQuick and http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide_QtQuick_Tutorials